# Appending a recurrent layer to PyTorch LSTM model with different hidden size

Tags: python, lstm, pytorch

I'm developing a BI-LSTM model for sequence analysis using PyTorch. For which I am using [`torch.nn.LSTM`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=lstm#torch.nn.LSTM). Using that module, you can have several layers with just passing a parameter `num_layers` to be the number of layers (e.g., `num_layers=2`). However all of them will have the same `hidden_size` which is *partially* fine for me, I just want to have all of them the same `hidden_size` **but** the last layer  with a different size. Basic example follows:

```
rnn = nn.LSTM(input_size=10, hidden_size=20, num_layers=2)
inp = torch.randn(5, 3, 10)
h0 = torch.randn(2, 3, 20)
c0 = torch.randn(2, 3, 20)
output, (hn, cn) = rnn(inp, (h0, c0))
```

The output dim is (`5, 3,`**`20`**)

One solution *(But unfavorable to me)* is implementing extra model that outputs the dimension I need and takes the input from the first model, e.g.,:

```
rnn_two = nn.LSTM(input_size=20, hidden_size=2)
output2, _ = rnn_two(output)
```

However, I do not wanna do this because I **parallelize** the model using [`DataParallel`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#dataparallel-functions-multi-gpu-distributed), so I need all to be one package. I was hoping to find something similar to keras, e.g.,:

```
rnn.add(LSTM, hidden_size=2)
```

I have checked the [LSTM source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/rnn.html#LSTM) but couldn't find what I need.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken this can be done like this:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class RnnWith2HiddenSizesModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RnnWith2HiddenSizesModel, self).__init__()
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(input_size=10, hidden_size=20, num_layers=2)
        self.rnn_two = nn.LSTM(input_size=20, hidden_size=2)

    def forward(self, inp, hc):
        output, _ = self.rnn(inp, hc)
        output2, _ = self.rnn_two(output)
        return output2


inp = torch.randn(5, 3, 10)
h0 = torch.randn(2, 3, 20)
c0 = torch.randn(2, 3, 20)

rnn = RnnWith2HiddenSizesModel()

output = RnnWith2HiddenSizesModel()(inp, (h0, c0))


tensor([[[-0.0305,  0.0327],
     [-0.1534, -0.1193],
     [-0.1393,  0.0474]],

    [[-0.0370,  0.0519],
     [-0.2081, -0.0693],
     [-0.1809,  0.0826]],

    [[-0.0561,  0.0731],
     [-0.2307, -0.0229],
     [-0.1780,  0.0901]],

    [[-0.0612,  0.0891],
     [-0.2378,  0.0164],
     [-0.1760,  0.0929]],

    [[-0.0660,  0.1023],
     [-0.2176,  0.0508],
     [-0.1611,  0.1053]]], grad_fn=<CatBackward>)
```

Comment: Could you, please, post your references. Also, you sure this design won’t affect the model parallelism?

Comment: Please post a working example too with the expected output.

Comment: I fixed an answer. As to the references, I just checked the docs of [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_nn/two_layer_net_module.html#pytorch-custom-nn-modules). As to my understanding, the parallelism is being made by data, so custom Module shouldn't affect it.

Answer (score 2):

Although the fact that @Mikhail Berlinkov's answer is working as needed, it's not generalized to a general case (which is not even requested in the question), for which I would like to propose a second solution:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from functools import reduce

class RNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, *models):
        super(RNNModel, self).__init__()
        self.models = models

    def forward(self, inp):
        return reduce(lambda arg, model: model(arg, None)[0], self.models, inp)
```

And can be called as:

```
rnn = nn.LSTM(input_size=10, hidden_size=20, num_layers=2)
rnn_two = nn.LSTM(input_size=20, hidden_size=2)
inp = torch.randn(5, 3, 10)

rnn_model = RNNModel(rnn, rnn_two)

output = rnn_model(inp)
```

`output.shape` is equal to the expected (i.e., `5,3,2`)